# setTimeout behaving weirdly in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

The objective is to delay execute a function after 1000/2000 ms. Even when `delay=0` actual delay introduced is around 1000ms

In the below code when `mm==0` and `ss==19`,  the second `console.log` is printing after around 1000ms. When I set delay=1000 it prints after around 2000 seconds. Any idea what could be wrong?

It's on Firefox 56 version. This version offers some exceptional convenience which isn't there in latest versions.

**Simplified Code**

```
var d = new Date();
var mm = d.getMinutes();
var ss = d.getSeconds();
var  delay = 0;
if (mm == 0 && ss <= 20)
    {
       
        console.log("Current time1=" + new Date().getTime())
    }

var fun = function ()
    {
        console.log("Current time2=" + new Date().getTime())
       
      
    }

setTimeout(fun, delay);
```

**Actual Code**

```
var d = new Date();
var mm = d.getMinutes();
var ss = d.getSeconds();
var delay = 0;

if (mm == 0 && ss <= 20)
    {
        delay =
                gg_user_selections.bid_details.login_delay_offset_20;
        console.log("Extra delay introdu:" + delay);
    }

var fun9 = function ()
    {
        if (mm == 0 && ss <= 20)
            {
                console.log("Extra delay introdu1:" + delay);
            }
        ff_do_embed_code(
                function ()
                    {
                        $("#btnLogin").click();
                    }
        );
        gg_last_login_click_time = new Date().getTime();

        $(".modalPop").show();
    }

setTimeout(fun9, delay);
```

Comment: Timeouts in inactive/backgrounded tabs are throttled to 1 second in Chrome and apparently in Firefox.

Comment: Maybe it's time to update your FF, the current version is 92.

Comment: @Teemu also, the oldest supported ESR is 78. The latest ESR is 91. 56 is way behind even those.

Comment: Sorry version 56 offers some special restart facility which isn't there in latest versions

Comment: @wOxxOm is there any about:config setting to disable  background tabs throttle?